# itextSharp datatable to pdf base64 string - pdf damaged

Tags: c#, pdf, base64

I am trying to get a pdf from datatable and attach it to an entity in CRM. For that purpose I use this code. Unfortunately created pdf is broken, I am unable to open it. Any ideas?

```
private static string ExportToBase64Pdf(DataTable dt, string entityName)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            document.Open();
            Font font5 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
            float[] widths = new float[dt.Columns.Count];

            for (int i =0; i<dt.Columns.Count; i++) { widths[i] = 4f; }
            table.SetWidths(widths);
            table.WidthPercentage = 100;

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(entityName));

            cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
            }

            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[i].ToString(), font5));
                }
            }
            document.Add(table);

            var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            var encodedPDF = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            document.Close();
            return encodedPDF;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You retrieve the document bytes before the document is finished by closing:

```
        var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        var encodedPDF = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        document.Close();
```

Move the close call before the ToArray call.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you elaborate a bit why does that make such a big difference? :))

Comment: When `Document.Close` is called, the `PdfWriter` finalises the pdf, in particular it writes the pdf object cross references and the file trailer, both parts that can not be written before closing. Thus, your original code retrieved an incomplete pdf.