# Transform IText7 to base64 C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, itext7

Im reading a pdf, populating its fields and then I create a new PDF, but I need to transform in a base64, not write on the disk.

Edit1: now im getting on my stream a 15 bytes string, maybe something is wrong ?

This is my code:

```
public static void GenerateFilledPDF(string inputFile, string outputPath)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
        var writer = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);

        var fields = form.GetFormFields();
        foreach (var field in fields.Keys)
        {
            fields[field].SetValue("ESTES");
        }

        form.FlattenFields();

        var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        var encodedPDF = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        pdfDoc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: well, what APIs does that have? is there an API to write it to a `Stream`? if so: can you write it to a `MemoryStream`? Once you have that: `Convert.ToBase64String`

Comment: ^^ iText should provide you with a `PdfWriter` with which you can write to a `MemoryStream`. Be inspired by : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278162/itextsharp-datatable-to-pdf-base64-string-pdf-damaged

Comment: As in the answer to the linked question: Move the `close` _before_ `memoryStream.ToArray()`

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I opt for marking the dupe, too. Question and Answer combined are the answer to this, basically, so not my merit. I just happen to have found it.

Comment: In any case you get my upvote.

Comment: Indeed, this is a duplicate. It does not matter that this question is about iText 7 and the duplicate target about iText 5 or earlier, the issue is knowing that one should retrieve the contents of the `MemoryStream` only after having finished writing to it, at least if one wants to retrieve the complete data.